# Find the last smaller or equal number for every element in the array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I have been given an array. I need to find the last (right-most) smaller or equal number for every element in the array.

For example:

`2 5 1 6 4 7`

2 has last smaller or equal number 1,
5 has last smaller or equal number 4 and not 1, etc.

Another example:

`5 100 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1`

Here, every element has last smaller or equal number 1. I know the naive approach, i.e. O(n²), but need a better approach.

Comment: Please explain the logic behind "last minimum", how did you arrive at 1 as "last minimum" for 2?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen, For an element we check all those elements on the right which are smaller and we pick the last smaller.

Comment: I think what he means is that for every number, he needs to find in the remaining array a number which is less than current, and the last such number is the last minimum.

Comment: I guess the last minimum doesn't exist for least number like, There will be no last minimum for `1`

Comment: @Ishpreet, For 1, we can do simply 1.

Comment: Can you explain what will be the least minimum in case of non unique list, Like for `2 4 2 3 4`, What will be the least minimum for 2?

Comment: @Ishpreet, Starting from last, we have last minimum at index 2 supposing array is 0-indexed.

Comment: What should be an answer? Another array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could go from right to left and build a min array of the minimum number until now.
For your example `2 5 1 6 4 7`, it would be:
Start at rightmost position:

```
7
4 7    (4 < 7)
4 4 7  (6 > 4)
...
```

So the min array for your example would be: `1 1 1 4 4 7`

Now for each query, you start at the same position in the min array and go right until finding a number which is greater:

For 2:

```
2 5 1 6 4 7
1 1 1 4 4 7
^
------^
```

First element greater than 2 is 4, so return number just before = 1

For 5:

```
2 5 1 6 4 7
1 1 1 4 4 7
  ^
----------^
```

First element greater than 5 is 7, so return number just before = 4

To find efficiently the first element greater for each element in the input array you can use upper_bound algorith (example in C++ http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/upper_bound/) to find the first element which is greater

Upper_bound takes log(N) time, so overall time to process every element in input array is O(NlogN)

Memory complexity is linear for the min array

Comment: Amazing explaination l!!

Comment: @MBo not sure I follow you... with above idea i do not compute all results in one pass, maybe you found something smarter?

Comment: @arenard  Oh, yes, my fault. Binary search or `upper_bound` at the right part of min array is good solution. So overall time is `O(NlogN)`