# How to find the rightmost number in the array which is greater or equal to current one in O(N) time?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

given an array `nums` of integers with length `n`, for each index `i`, I am trying to find the rightmost index `j` such that `i < j` and `nums[j] >= nums[i]`. Is there an O(N) solution for this problem? I am aware of **monotonic stack** which could be used for this kind of problems, but unable to derive an algorithm.

For example, given an array A:
 `A = [9,8,1,0,1,9,4,0,4,1]`, the solution should output
 `[5,5,9,9,9,-1,8,9,-1,-1]`. Here `-1` indicates no indices satisfy the constraint.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69758652/how-to-find-the-rightmost-number-in-the-array-which-is-greater-or-equal-to-curre) asked the same question, and the accepted answer is only for O(NlogN). I'd like to know whether an O(N) solution is possible.

Thank you.

***Update***

Based on @Aivean's answer, here is an **O(Nlog(N))** solution in python.

```
def rightmostGreaterOrEqual(nums):
    A, n = nums, len(nums)    
    indx = [-1]*n 
    stack, stackv = [], []
    for i in range(n-1, -1, -1):
        if not stack or nums[stack[-1]] < nums[i]:
            stack.append(i) 
            stackv.append(nums[i])
        else:
            idx = bisect.bisect_left(stackv, nums[i])
            indx[i] = stack[idx]
    return indx

B = [9,8,1,0,1,9,4,0,4,1]
rightGreat = rightmostGreaterOrEqual(B)
print(B)
[9, 8, 1, 0, 1, 9, 4, 0, 4, 1]
print(rightGreat)
[5, 5, 9, 9, 9, -1, 8, 9, -1, -1]
```

Comment: Have you searched for the problem? What did you find?

Comment: This link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51780798/find-the-last-smaller-or-equal-number-for-every-element-in-the-array asked the same question, and the accepted answer is only for O(NlogN). I'd like to know whether an O(N) solution is possible.

Comment: Just traverse your array from right to left, checking and filling the monotonic stack (ascending). The top of the stack would be the answer for each element. [Check this similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69653317/1349366). This will have O(n) time.

Comment: @Aivean I don't see how that works for [0, 3, 2,-1]. Are you saying 0 will match with -1 or 3? Because neither is correct.

Comment: Please add your research to the question text above.

Comment: @גלעדברקן, you're right. I misread the question. Then the best solution I could think of is to form the supplementary strictly decreasing subsequence of the elements of `nums` (paired with their indices) and do binary search to get answer for each element. That would be O(n log n) in total.

Comment: Or the approach could be inverted, first put all elements of `nums` into min priority Q, then traverse `nums` from right to left, fetching elements from the Q that are less than current element and recording current element as the answer for them. Still (n log n).

Comment: Wait. This doesn't make sense. Have you forgotten to mention a constraint that  `j > i` in the description? Otherwise, why  `answer[9] = -1` ?  `nums[9] == 1` and there is `j=8` where `nums[8]=4`. So `answer[9]` should be `8`  according to the constraints that you've stated.

Comment: Yes, the constraint is j > i. The main question added it.

Comment: And are you sure that `j` should be **rightmost**, not **leftmost**? That's the difference between O(n log n) and O(n).

Comment: In fact, I'd also like to find the ***leftmost*** ```j``` such that ```j < i``` and ```nums[j >= nums[i]```. I thought it is symmetrical to the **rightmost**, maybe not? @Aivean, could you give an O(N) solution for finding the ***leftmost*** ```j```?

Comment: @bssrdf, see my first comment in this thread. For **leftmost** solution you need to maintain monotonic stack and can find answer in O(1) for each element. For **rightmost** solution you'll have to maintain a BST and look up each answer in O(log n). Both solutions assume traversing `nums` from right to left.

Comment: @Aivean, I don't get your arguments for **leftmost** O(N) vs **rightmost** O(NlogN).  If we can have O(N) solution for **leftmost**, can't we use it on the **rightmost** problem by reversing the array?

Comment: @bssrdf, please check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two problems of finding **leftmost** and **rightmost** `j` for a given `i` are not symmetrical, because of the added constraint of `i < j`. When I'm talking about these two tasks I assume that the constraint `i < j` is **not** flipped. This constraint means, that we always look to the **right** of `i` when searching for `j`, whether we're looking for **rightmost** or **leftmost** `j`. Without this constraint two tasks would be symmetrical.

---

#### 1. Finding **rightmost** `j`, such that `i < j` and `nums[i] ≤ nums[j]`

One way to solve this task, is to traverse `nums` from right to left and maintain the strictly increasing subsequence of already visited elements (with their indices). Current element is added to the sequence only if it's larger, than the largest element already present in the sequence. Adding new element into the sequence is O(1).

For each element of `nums` you have to perform binary search in the subsequence of the visited elements to find the value that is larger or equals than the current element. Binary search is O(log n).

The total time is O(n log n), the auxiliary space needed is O(n).

Here is the graphical representation of the problem:

[image]

Here yellow dots represent the elements that form strictly increasing sequence (and their `answer` will be -1). Every other element (in blue) picks one of the ranges formed by yellow elements.

---

#### 2. Finding **leftmost** j, such that `i < j` and `nums[i] ≤ nums[j]`

This problem, as opposed to the previous one, can be solved in O(n) time and O(n) space using monotonic stack. Similar to the previous problem, as you traverse `nums` from right to left, you form and maintain a monotonic stack, but, importantly, when new element is added to the stack all elements that are smaller are removed from the stack. And instead of using binary search to find the larger element, the answer is right at the new top of the stack (after all smaller elements were removed). This makes updating the stack and finding the answer for each element amortized O(1).

[image]

Here yellow elements represent elements with `answer = -1`, when they were added to the stack, they emptied the stack completely, as they were larger than every other element in the stack.

Comment: Fair enough. I got what you mean by **rightmost** and **leftmost** ```j``` now. Yes, monotonic stack is exactly the right data structure for case 2. Thanks for your clear solution (and graphics) to case 1. Upvoted.

Comment: @bssrdf please check Matt Timmermans answer for the proof of why "rightmost j" task cannot be done faster than in O(n log n).

Answer (score 4):

There is not going to be an O(N) algorithm for the problem as written.  Given a function that solves this problem, you could use it to partition N/2 arbitrary numbers into N/2 arbitrary adjacent ranges.

For example [2532,1463,3264,200,4000,3000,2000,1000] produces [5,6,4,7,-1,-1,-1,-1], identifying the ranges of the first N/2 numbers.

If you can only relate the numbers by comparison, then this will take you N/2 * log(N/2) comparisons, so O(N log N) time.

Without a limit on the size of the numbers, which would let you cheat like a radix sort, there isn't going to be way that is asymptotically faster than all comparison-based methods.

Comment: I agree with your conclusion, but the explanation is not quite clear to me. Are you saying that this problem is isomorphic to the sorting, and, since you can't sort faster than `O(n log n)` (in general case), this proves that this problem is also `O(n log n)`?

Comment: Yes, but not with sorting.  Distributing into arbitrary bins is similar to sorting, and the same argument applies.

Comment: Ok, I get your point, but can you please give a link to the definition of the partitioning problem that you're referring to? I'm not quite sure that you're correct, for example, consider an input array that ends with it's maximum element. The answer in this case will be the last index for all elements. How does this result help with partitioning?

Comment: Sorry, no link, since it's off the top of my head. Easy to prove, though -- there are m^m distinct ways to distribute m items into m bins, so it takes log_2(m^m) = m * log_2(m) bits to identify one particular way.  You get one bit per comparison.  Not *every* instance of the problem does this.  But look in my example at how I distributed 4 numbers into 4 bins with a range of 1000 each.

Comment: I finally understood what you mean. I think it's easier explained with sorting. Having the list of numbers, if we sort it in descending order and append to itself (left part is unsorted and the right part is sorted) then the function in question will have to effectively sort the left part of the list, which we know can't be faster than O(n log n). Thank you for the insight.